# extracting lines by comparing two lines through nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, compare, line, extract

Suppose I have a text file having the following lines...

Display
B
User
D
E
Response
F

I want to extract the value D and E inside an array though nodejs...How do I achieve this?

Comment: Where is the comparison?

Comment: How do i compare User and Response so that i can obtain the values in between

Comment: Next time try to make clear what you're asking. Edit your question adding more information about the problem. There is no hints in your question about you want results between User and Response.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

// we will save the result in this array
const result = []

let afterUser = false

const rl = readline.createInterface(fs.createReadStream('text.txt'))

const listener = rl.on('line', line => {
  // finish the listener if we reach Response line
  if (line === 'Response') {
    rl.close()
    return
  }

  // if we are after User line push the item to the array
  if (afterUser) {
    result.push(line)
  }

  // we'll set afterUser to true if we detect the User line
  if (!afterUser && line === 'User') {
    afterUser = true
  }
})

// after finish reading the file we can show the result
rl.on('close', () => {
  console.log(result)
})
```